# AS3 - Why am I getting this 1009 error? (Cannot access a property or method of a null object)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I can't get this program to work.  I Always get this error: `Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference`. 
I don't understand why and would appreciate some help.

Here's my code:

Main class:

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var enginge:Engine = new Engine(stage);
        private var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(100, 100);

        public function Main():void 
        {
            addChild(enemy);
        }
    }
}
```

Engine class:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Engine 
    {
        public static var stage:Stage;
        public static var gravity:int = 1;

        public function Engine(stage:Stage) 
        {
            Engine.stage = stage;
        }

        public static function gravitate(object:Sprite):void
        {
            object.y += Engine.gravity;

            if (object.y < Engine.stage.stageHeight - object.height / 2)
            {
                Engine.gravity += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Engine.gravity = 0;
                object.y = Engine.stage.stageHeight - object.height / 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enemy class:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Enemy extends Sprite
    {
        private var gravity:int = 1;

        public function Enemy(x:int, y:int) 
        {
            this.graphics.beginFill(1, 1);
            this.graphics.drawRect(this.x - 25, this.y - 40, 50, 80);
            this.graphics.endFill();

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event):void
            {
                Engine.gravitate(this);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error msgs have a line number reference of where the error occurs. Without that we can't possibly determine what is causing the error

Comment: The error is at line 22 in Enemy class: "Engine.gravitate(this);"

Comment: AS3 isn't javascript,  anonymous functions are generally frowned upon (and is especially inefficient in an enter frame handler).  While i doubt it will change your issue, consider not using the anonymous function as your enter frame handler

Comment: billion time asked, and billion time same answer: don't use stage in constructor that's illogical since it's always null at that point.

Comment: @BotMaster - if you look at the code you'll see the OP passes in a reference to the stage in the constructor...

Comment: if you look at the code you'll see that is doing it during variable declaration where no stage is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix the problem you need to get rid of the anonymous function in the Enemy class.

You will have:

```
  public function Enemy(x:int, y:int)
  {
        this.graphics.beginFill(1, 1);
        this.graphics.drawRect(this.x - 25, this.y - 40, 50, 80);
        this.graphics.endFill();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,handler);
  }

  private function handler(event:Event):void
  {
        Engine.gravitate(Sprite(this));
  }
```

and the code will be working. This is due to context difference of word **this** inside anonymous function.

Usage of anonymous function is terrible practice and you should refrain from doing it.